# Counting from a list of polynomials

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following list of rational functions:

```
l={(1.92593 x + 156.713 x^2 + 984.928 x^3 + 2835.89 x^4 + 4790.17 x^5 + 
    6312.74 x^6 + 6361.5 x^7 + 4893.32 x^8 + 2894.32 x^9 + 
    1291.06 x^10 + 408.032 x^11 + 92.1898 x^12 + 16.5306 x^13 + 
    2.35827 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (0.962963 x + 
    153.004 x^2 + 1011.72 x^3 + 2964.87 x^4 + 4935.08 x^5 + 
    6585.44 x^6 + 6458.25 x^7 + 4863.74 x^8 + 2672.89 x^9 + 
    1103.88 x^10 + 311.636 x^11 + 69.3013 x^12 + 10.4081 x^13 + 
    1.17914 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (3.85185 x + 
    151.15 x^2 + 1008.14 x^3 + 2935.63 x^4 + 4950.81 x^5 + 
    6367.76 x^6 + 6316.97 x^7 + 4809.03 x^8 + 2847.33 x^9 + 
    1204.67 x^10 + 389.545 x^11 + 90.9182 x^12 + 12.8571 x^13 + 
    1.76871 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (0.962963 x + 
    153.004 x^2 + 1192.99 x^3 + 3370.73 x^4 + 5298.59 x^5 + 
    6738.54 x^6 + 6391.45 x^7 + 4497.74 x^8 + 2426.53 x^9 + 
    924.928 x^10 + 264.098 x^11 + 45.1412 x^12 + 6.12244 x^13 + 
    1.17914 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (1.92593 x + 
    142.804 x^2 + 957.246 x^3 + 2757.64 x^4 + 4703.23 x^5 + 
    6194.73 x^6 + 6419.86 x^7 + 4933.98 x^8 + 2976.2 x^9 + 
    1339.05 x^10 + 437.082 x^11 + 109.356 x^12 + 18.9796 x^13 + 
    1.76871 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14)}
```

I would plot them between `0<x<1` using:

```
Plot[{1, l[[1 ;; 5]]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

which would give:

[image]

Now I want to count the number of polynomials that are above the line 1 in different intervals, for instance there are 5 of them (all) that are above 1 between `0<x<0.2`, then there are 3 of them above line for `0.2<x<0.4`
and so on. Surely I plotted them to see them but I presume there should be a way to count those lines that are above 1 at each interval just using the list `l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[Total@UnitStep[l - 1], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Transpose@{#, N@Reduce[{# == Total@UnitStep[Rationalize[l, 10^-12] - 1], 
  0 <= x <= 1}, x] & /@ #} &@Range[0, 5], Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  0 & 0.470394<x\leq 1. \\
> \hline
>  1 & 0.233586<x\leq 0.470394 \\
> \hline
>  2 & 0.200019<x\leq 0.233586 \\
> \hline
>  3 & 0.\leq x<0.0027398\lor 0.188081<x\leq 0.200019 \\
> \hline
>  4 & 0.0027398\leq x<0.00284485\lor 0.110004<x\leq 0.188081 \\
> \hline
>  5 & 0.00284485\leq x\leq 0.110004 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$